# how to create a new method using an url and an api_key as parameters and then concatenate them in ruby 2.5.3?

Tags: ruby, api, methods

How can i create a new method with an url and a api_key as parameters?
and then concatenate the api_key to the url?

for example:

```
def method1(url, api_key)
  # concatenate them: www.abcde.com/fghy&api_key
end
```

Comment: What is `url`? What is `api_key`? `http://www.abcde.com/fghy&api_key` is not a valid URL format. Please try to provide a [mcve] of the question.

Comment: My naive answer, based on the very limited information you've provided:: Just return a string like: `"#{url}?api_key=#{api_key}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use String Interpolation

There are multiple ways to do this in Ruby, but simple is often best. For example, using `#{}` String [interpolation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings):

```rb
def url_with_api_key(url, api_key)
  "#{url}?api_key=#{api_key}"
end

url_with_api_key 'https://example.com', 'foobarbaz'
#=> "https://example.com?api_key=foobarbaz"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `URI` module to ensure that everything is encoded correctly:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.abcde.com/fghy")
uri.query = "api_key=key_with_special_characters <>&"

uri.to_s
#=> "http://www.abcde.com/fghy?api_key=key_with_special_characters%20%3C%3E&"
```

Comment: Or maybe even `uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(api_key: '...')`